# Poincaré-like inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be an open bounded set. Let $\partial\Omega=\Gamma^1\cup\Gamma^2$, with $\Gamma^1\cap\Gamma^2=\emptyset$. We denote as $\Gamma^1_j$, $j=1,\dots,p_{\Gamma^1}+1$, the connected components of $\Gamma^1$. Define
$$
H^1_\ast(\Omega):=\{ \xi\in H^1(\Omega):\xi_{|{\Gamma^1_j}}\,\mbox{is constant}\,\forall\ j=1,\dots,p_{\Gamma^1}, \xi_{|\Gamma^1_{p_{\Gamma^1}+1}}=0\}.
$$
I read in some articles that Poincaré inequality holds for functions in $H^1_\ast(\Omega)$, i.e. there exists $C>0$ such that
$$
||\xi||_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C ||\nabla\xi ||_{L^2(\Omega)},
$$
for every $\xi\in H^1_\ast(\Omega)$.
 Any hint?

Comment: Should $\Omega$ be connected as well? What if $\Omega$ is disjoint two balls and $\Gamma^1$ and $\Gamma^2$ are the boundaries of the separate balls. With effectively no conditions on $\Gamma^2$, I don't see what stops $\xi = 0$ on the first ball and $\xi = C$ on the second ball.